# Can I find out how many Dragons I have killed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I can access the stats and see how many dragon *souls* I have collected, but I've been killing dragons all over the place, sometimes ones I've already beaten that therefore don't give off a soul.

Is there another statistic that I have missed that will tell me how many I've dispatched, or should I have been keeping a manual tally by scratching them into my wall à la prisoners in jail counting down the number of years they have remaining.

Comment: It won't help you now, but the unofficial skyrim patch (in the steam workshop) will fix the "respawned dragons don't give souls" bit.

Comment: Ah, I'm an XBOX guy though, so no help to me (unless it's also rolling out to consoles).  I didn't realise that's a bug; I figured it was intentional.

Comment: Ah, you're out of luck for the time being then. Essentially what's happening is that the game is resurrecting the dragon you've already killed, rather than spawning a new one, and resurrecting a creature doesn't set the appropriate "you can take this guy's soul again" flags.

Answer (score 2):

On the PC, you can use the console command `help DragonsKilled` to find out how many dragons you have slain.

Comment: This isn't much help to you as an Xbox player, but here it is for any PC players who may stumble upon this.

Answer (score 1):

Go to general stats, this can be done by pressing the start button on the right side of you're controller, then you press the RT button on the right side, after you want to go to magic exactly 4 down. And then in the stats of you're magic you want to look at the "Dragon Souls Collected", which is 4 down. And how many souls that are there is the amount of dragons you have killed.

Comment: This is only for Xbox360 and playstation4.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is not possible. The only way is to check the ammount of dragon souls but you've already done this.

Comment: dARGON sOULS CAN BE USED UP, SO THIS QUESTION DIESN'T ADD ANYTHING.

Answer (score -4):

all you have to do is add the amount of shouts you have ACTIVE(this counts for each individual part of the shout), to the amount of dragon souls you have remaining, then your left with the number of dragon souls you have collected in total(not including respawned dragons. not that this is important).

Comment: The question author stated that he already is able to tell how many dragon souls he has. This really doesn't answer his question.